# How to prove if $G$ is a group with every non-identity element having order 2 and $H$ is a subgroup, $G/H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This isn't a homework problem.  I'm preparing for an exam, and I have no idea how to solve this problem.

> Let $G$ is a group such that every non-identity element has order $2$.  Let $H$ be a subgroup.  Prove $G/H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$.

The fact that every non-identity element has order $2$ means $G$ is abelian (since for all $a, b \in G, (ab)(ab) = e \implies ba = a^{-1}b^{-1}$, but $a = a^{-1}$ since $a^{2} = e$, and likewise $b= b^{-1}$, so $ba = ab$).

Since $G$ is abelian, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.  So $G/H$ is a group.  Now what?  I know that subgroups of $G/H$ are in $1-1$ correspondence with subgroups of $G$ containing $H$.  Does this help?

Comment: $G$ is a vector space over the two element field $F_2$; then the dimension of $G/H$ over $F_2$ is at most the dimension of $G$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $G$ is Abelian, I’ll write it additively. Say that $A\subseteq G$ is *independent* if $\sum F\ne 0_G$ for all finite $F\subseteq A$. Use Zorn’s lemma to get a maximal independent $B\subseteq G$. Show that for each $x\in G$ there is a finite $F_x\subseteq B$ such that $x=\sum F_x$; then show that $F_x$ is unique and infer that $G$ is a vector space over $\Bbb F_2$ with basis $B$.

Now modify the construction by first getting a basis $B_H$ for $H$ and then extending it to a basis $B$ for $G$, and show that $G/H$ is isomorphic to the subgroup generated by $B\setminus B_H$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  Your answer is clear and doesn't leave out any important details.  You clearly know how to teach/communicate math.

Comment: I agree. Wish the other 100K plus reputation would give an answer of the quality of Brian's answers. IT is always a pleasure to read Brian's answers. Hagen's answer is not really helpful.

Comment: @Learner: In fairness, I would say that Hagen’s answer is good in itself; after all, it’s just a terser version of mine! But it assumes a bit more background than the OP has, so it wasn’t as helpful/useful here and now.

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot: Thank *you*. Much as I like mathematics, I’ve always thought of myself as a teacher first and a mathematician second, so that’s very nice to hear.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Why should one use Zorn's lemma to infer that an elementary $2$-group is a vector space over the two element field?

Comment: @egreg: I didn't, really: I used it to get a basis, and then to get a basis useful for solving the problem.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott “and infer that $G$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with basis $B$” should then be fixed.

Comment: @egreg: There's nothing to fix: the conclusion that you quote does follow from the argument sketched. That you might prefer a different argument for the first part of the conclusion is irrelevant.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The fact that $G$ is a vector space over $F_2$ is completely independent of the argument for find $B$: you don't infer this from the existence of $B$.

Comment: @egreg: I am well aware that the existence of the base is not needed in order to see that this is a vector space over $\Bbb F_2$. So what? Having the base makes it completely obvious if it wasn't already and is needed subsequently anyway. (And I'm in bed typing on a Kindle, which is a royal pain, so even if you feel obliged to continue, you'll have to wait a few hours for a response.)

Answer (score 2):

$G$ is an elementary $2$-group, so it's a vector space over the field $F_2$ with two elements. Every subgroup is thus a direct summand.

Comment: What is a direct summand?  You mean $G$ is a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{F}_{2}$?

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot Every subgroup is a vector subspace, so it has a complement.

Comment: I appreciate your time and willingness to answer my question.  But your answer is too brief for me and so didn't help me very much.

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot What's precisely you don't understand?

Comment: What is a $2$-group?  How does this imply $G$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$?  How does this imply every subgroup is a direct summand?  What is a direct summand?

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot, It's hard to understand how you don't know what a direct summand, a basic and rather important notion in linear algebra say, is, if you're trying to study group theory, which is usually  more advanced than linear algebra.

Comment: @Timbuc How does this comment help me?

Comment: I think a lot and in several ways, @MathIsHardNoItsNot: (1) If you're studying on your own you may be doing things not in the right order, (2) It will help everybody if next time you write down what you know and what you don't, (3) It could be a good idea if you found out the usual, standard order different things are taught in most univiersities: you tagged your question "abstract algebra" , "group theory" , and your question is not beginners in group theory (though not advances either)==> most people will assume you already had at least a first course in linear algebra, direct sums and etc.

Comment: @Timbuc You should consider that *maybe* it is possible I am familiar with the concept of a direct summand, except not in name.  In this case, it might be helpful to suggest "well, think about the span of two linearly independent vectors in linear algebra -- this is really a direct sum of the span of each vector, and so this is all that a direct summand is."  This is how you can respond in a more constructive way, rather than commenting about your disbelief that I don't know what a direct summand is being at this level.

Comment: @Timbuc This site is all about people engaging in math and discussing it with each other.  Yet sometimes, and in this specific case, the level of engagement is low, and to me that is very sad.  The two answers to this question look like they have been formulated for a textbook, where usually brevity is preferred because there are only finitely many pages.  Well, this site isn't a textbook, and I personally don't like answers that are brief and assume the person that asked the question is already at the level to receive such short responses.  If that were true, the question wouldn't be asked...

Comment: Don't be sad, @MathIsHardNoItsNot: why don't you better try to understand why the answers were given that way? I think they were because people assumed you already know and are familiar with all that stuff, as it is usually expected from someone taking a course in group theory. And this site has loads of members  that won't usually give unnecessary long and detailed answers but rather will write some hints and let part of the work for the asker.  About you telling me in your first comment how to respond constructively: this depends on each individual, I think.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of linear algebra: $G$ is a vector space over  the field $\mathbb F_2$ and the subspace $H$ ha a complement.

Let's stay in group theory, though:
Let $K<G$ be a maximal subgroup with $K\cap H=1$ (use Zorn's lemma). Show that $G/H\approx K$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why $G$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$.  To be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$, every element should be able to be written as a linear combination of some basis elements with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_{2}$, but I don't see it...

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot: $G$ being Abelian, I write it additively. Say that $A\subseteq G$ is *independent* if $\sum F\ne 0_G$ for all finite $F\subseteq A$. Use Zorn’s lemma to get a maximal independent $B\subseteq G$. Show that for each $x\in G$ there is a finite $F_x\subseteq B$ such that $x=\sum F_x$; then show that $F_x$ is unique, and infer that $G$ is a vector space over $\Bbb F_2$ with basis $B$. Now modify the construction by first getting a basis $B_H$ for $H$ and then extending this to a basis $B$ for $G$, and show that $G/H$ is isomorphic to the subgroup generated by $B\setminus B_H$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott By $A \subseteq G$ being independent, do you mean no sum of elements of $A$ can be $0$?

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot: Almost: I defined it to mean that no finite sum can be $0_G$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ok, thank you for the clear instructions and help.  I understood everything you said and will follow those steps to prove the statement.  One last thing: I know it might be annoying to write everything out again, but I would like to accept your answer for this question.  Do you mind reposting the information as your own answer?

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot: I can do that; just give me a couple of minutes.